# creating a polygon that covers other polygons layer using python

Tags: python, polygon, geopandas, area

I have a layer with polygons (buildings) and I would like create a polygon that limits the area where the polygons are using geopandas or other python module

SO I have these buildings:

[image]

and I would like to have a new layer with a polygon that covers all buildings:

[image]

so this:

[image]

where it covers the building polygons area .
It can be that also a polygon that covers all the buildings and not goes exactly on the vertices of the outside buildings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `geopandas` you could apply `unary_union` to create a multipolygon out of your polygons and then use `convex_hull`:

```
import geopandas as gpd
gdf1 = gpd.read_file(r"C:\Users\X\Desktop\testpoly.shp")
gdf2 = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=[gdf1.unary_union.convex_hull], crs="EPSG:4326")
gdf1.plot()
gdf2.plot()
```

[image]